# Prevent CSV injection in Data unload to CSV files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, export-to-csv

We are running unload query in snowflake to export data into the AWS S3 bucket as CSV files.
As we are exporting data into CSV files, there is a possibility of CSV injection.

How can we tell snowflake to add CSV injection protection?

Comment: Hi - what sort of csv injection protection are you expecting and why do you think this is something Snowflake should be doing? If your data in Snowflake is “risky” when exported to csv why aren’t you sanitising it in Snowflake before you export it?

Comment: Ya. it is sanitized one. As part of the bureaucratic process, I need to show CSV injection prevention to the security team. so

Comment: OK - so what evidence do your security team require to show CSV injection prevention? Why is this part of the Snowflake/export process and not part of the process that consumes the CSV files? Even if the CSV files were "clean" when exported from Snowflake they could be tampered with before being consumed so your consuming application would still need to sanitise them - so sanitising them as part of the Snowflake export is pointless

Comment: we have a use case where the unloaded file generated by snowflake is directly shared with the user as a pre-signed S3 URL link. They are asking proof that this is not secured one

Comment: OK - then you will need to show the process you go through to sanitise the data and to export it (to show that the export doesn't change the data). There is no "magic bullet" that will do this for you

Answer (score 0):

While exporting the file in S3 bucket, the file is locked and I believe there is no chance to upload. The file picks up by snpwpipe only after the file is being finished exporting.